# OLE Automation date in lua

Tags: lua, ole

Ok, I really need OLE Automation date in lua.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> public double ToOADate()
>
> Return Value Type: System.Double A double-precision floating-point
>   number that contains an OLE Automation date equivalent to the value of
>   this instance.

So in C# this:

```
Console.Write("DateTime.Now.ToOADate() = " + DateTime.Now.ToOADate());
```

gives me this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToOADate() = 42146,4748270602
```

What is the best way to get simular value in Lua?

Comment: Is it simply the number of days since 1900?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff since 30.12.1899, yes.

Comment: In Lua `os.time()` gives number of seconds since 1970.  You can easily convert it to number of days.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff makes sence and works! If you be so kind to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it with "correct".

Comment: Sorry, I'm too lazy to write complete answers :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ok, no problem, I've answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more details, based on EgorSkriptunoff answer.

So, that Lua code works just fine for me to get OLE Automation date in lua:

```
-- number of days between December, 30 1899 and January, 1 1970
local magicnumber = 25569   
-- don't forget about time zone (UTC+3 for my case)
local utcshift = 3*3600
-- calc and print for test
local oleadate = magicnumber + ((os.time()+utcshift)/(3600*24))
print(oleadate)
```

Output:

```
42146.575740741
```