# Lua wireshark dissector extract timestamp in OLE automation format

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector, ole-automation

ref: [OLE Automation date in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391788/ole-automation-date-in-lua)

I'm writing a simple UDP dissector in LUA to decode packets that contain a timestamp that was encoded as an OLE automation date. The encoding results in an 8-byte data pattern:

```
C2 F5 4F 12 FD 6B E5 40
```

which decodes as 43871.90848539352 = '2/10/2020 9:48:13 PM'. In C# .NET this is via the DateTime.ToOADate() method (which works fine).

Here is my simplified dissector, which 'decodes' an 8-byte message that consists only of the timestamp:

```
local logger_proto = Proto("logger", "LOGGER")
local logger_hdr={
    atime = ProtoField.absolute_time("test.atime","test atime",base.UTC),
    rtime = ProtoField.relative_time("test.rtime","test rtime",base.UTC),
}
logger_proto.fields=logger_hdr

function logger_proto.init() end

function logger_proto.dissector(tvbuf, pktinfo, root)
    root:add(logger_hdr.atime,tvbuf:range(0,8))
    root:add(logger_hdr.atime,tvbuf:range(8,8))
end
```

In the test packet I send the timestamp twice, the second time is with the bytes in reverse order to test for endian issues (the 'grasping at straws' approach). The packet data is:

```
C2 F5 4F 12 FD 6B E5 40 40 E5 6B FD 12 4F F5 C2
```

the two retrieved timestamps are

```
Aug 25, 2073 03:14:26.-4360608 UTC
Jul  2, 2004 14:06:53.307230146 UTC
```

the 'correct' timestamp should be

```
Feb 10, 2020 21:48:13 UTC
```

It looks like ProtoField.absolute_time with base.UTC is not quite what I am looking for. So my questions are

1. Is there a ProtoField option to extract this timestamp correctly, in a format that excludes fractional seconds?
2. If not, how would I extract the date/time bytewise and make calculations to format the correct date by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to learn a bit about OLE dates but found relevant information at [DateTime.ToOADate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.8).  I also used information from the [OLE Automation date in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391788/ole-automation-date-in-lua) question as well as from [Convert us-timestamp to absolute_time](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/45308/convert-us-timestamp-to-absolute_time) to come up with a *possible* solution for you.  I doubt it's an optimal one, but it *seems* to work based on the data provided.  Hopefully it works for you but if not, it should get you closer to a solution.

A long-term solution would be if Wireshark could supply **native** support for OLE dates, and for that to happen, I'd recommend filing a Wireshark enhancement [bug report](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/) requesting just such a thing.

A *possible* solution (with some extra stuff for illustrative purposes):

```
local p_logger = Proto("logger", "LOGGER")
local logger_hdr = {
    -- Only the oletime_abs field is useful; the rest just help illustrate things
    -- and helped me during debugging.  Remove/rename as you see fit.

    oletime = ProtoField.double("logger.oletime", "OLE time"),

    -- Note: .int64 doesn't work so just using .int32
    oletime_days = ProtoField.int32("logger.oletime.days", "Days"),
    oletime_partial = ProtoField.double("logger.oletime.partial", "Partial"),
    oletime_abs = ProtoField.absolute_time("logger.oleabstime", "OLE Abs time", base.UTC)
}
p_logger.fields = logger_hdr

function p_logger.dissector(tvbuf, pinfo, tree)
    local logger_tree = tree:add(p_logger, tvbuf(0,-1))
    local OLE_DIFF_TO_UNIX = 25569
    local SECS_PER_DAY = 86400
    local oletime = tvbuf:range(0, 8):le_float() - OLE_DIFF_TO_UNIX
    local oletime_days = math.floor(oletime)
    local oletime_partial = (oletime - oletime_days) * SECS_PER_DAY
    local secs = oletime_days * SECS_PER_DAY + math.floor(oletime_partial)
    local nstime = NSTime.new(secs, 0)

    pinfo.cols.protocol:set("LOGGER")
    logger_tree:add(logger_hdr.oletime, tvbuf:range(0, 8), oletime)
    logger_tree:add(logger_hdr.oletime_days, tvbuf:range(0, 8), oletime_days)
    logger_tree:add(logger_hdr.oletime_partial, tvbuf:range(0, 8), oletime_partial)
    logger_tree:add(logger_hdr.oletime_abs, tvbuf:range(0, 8), nstime)
end

-- Register dissector (this particular registration is just for my testing)
local udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
udp_table:add(33333, p_logger)
```

I'm sure this can be cleaned up/optimized, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader.  Tested with the following hand-crafted packet:

```
0000   00 0e b6 00 00 02 00 0e b6 00 00 01 08 00 45 00   ..............E.
0010   00 37 00 00 40 00 40 11 b5 ea c0 00 02 65 c0 00   .7..@.@......e..
0020   02 66 82 35 82 35 00 23 e8 54 c2 f5 4f 12 fd 6b   .f.5.5.#.T..O..k
0030   e5 40 40 e5 6b fd 12 4f f5 c2 00 00 00 00 00 00   .@@.k..O........
0040   00 00 00 00 00                                    .....
```

... and you should get the following decode of the *"Logger"* OLE date:

```
LOGGER
    OLE time: 18302.9084853935
    Days: 18302
    Partial: 78493.1380001362
    OLE Abs time: Feb 10, 2020 21:48:13.000000000 UTC
```

You can use [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html) to convert it to a pcap file for testing.  For example: `text2pcap -a logger.txt logger.pcap` ... where `logger.txt` is a text file containing the raw packet bytes pasted above.

Comment: So the answer was to pass the calculated 'nstime' to the ProtoField.absolute_time field. I missed the conversion to UNIX format altogether.  Without native Wireshark or LUA support for OLE dates, this is the best solution, and it works in practice. Thanks!